# Get an id of UL having specific class

Tags: jquery, class, dom

i have a div that has a ul elemenet having class="bla" and id="foo"

```
<div class = new>
<ul class="bla" id="foo"><li>aa</li></ul>
</div>
```

how can i get id of the ul,, help is appreciable

Comment: Starting from...the div?

Comment: _i get id of the ul_ please elaborate.

Comment: how do you want to get that id..? there are many ways..? What's your context.?

Comment: i have 6 ul having same class , i want to select them by the  id to know which ul is clicked

Comment: @Jatt.net That is a *completely* different question, and is something you should have mentioned in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myEl = $('ul.bla').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.new ul.blah').attr('id')
```

specifc to uls, and the new container div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul[class=bla]').prop('id')
```

Will look up the ul element with the specific class bla.

prop('id') will get it's id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.new').find('ul.bla').attr('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

The id is considered a property of the ul, similar to the class and can both be used as selectors, so to use JQuery. you would use the class as the selector for the ul, and then access the ul property id.

```
$( '.class' ).prop( 'id' );
```

In this case it would return 'foo'.

EDIT ------

After seeing that you want to use those id's to select them, you could use one of these two methods.

```
var list = $( '#id' );
```

or

```
var list = $( '.class#id' );
```

The first method will work, but the second method is more explicit. Either one is acceptable though.